# Easy quick notifications on Windows 7 with UAC

Tags: windows-7, command-line, uac, notifications, at

On Windows XP I was used to create simple notifications for myself using combination of `at` and `msg` commands. The whole thing was very easy

1. hit `Ctrl+R`
2. type eg. `at 21:00 msg * Do something`
3. hit `Enter`

at the specified time a popup window with that message appeared.
With UAC in Win7 the at command requires administrative privileges and says that access is denied. 
Is there some easy, no new applications requiring way to have this?
Of course I could turn off UAC, but that seems like an overkill and is not something I would like to do because of notifications...

Answer (score 1):

You can preface your at command with [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28WS.10%29.aspx) and authenticate.
You'll need to double check the syntax, but something like:

```
runas /user:<localmachinename>\administrator "at 21:00 msg * Do something"
```

Comment: One caveat: If you are joined to a domain, the default administrator account is **not** autoelevated. So this would still prompt a UAC.